# Need help centering image in <td> that is also a link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a play icon in the center of a td cell whose entire content should also be the target of a link.  The cell has a background image that is larger than the centered play icon, and I need the anchor to apply to the entire cell (including background).

In the code below, the link only applies to the play icon.  Everything that I do to make the anchor apply to the entire cell breaks the centering (both vertical and horizontal) of the play icon. How do I do this?  Thanks!

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="244" height="186" style="background:bg-image.png no-repeat center;background-size:100%;text-align:middle">
    <a href="action.htm" style="height:100%;width:100%;" >
     <img src="icon_play.png"/>
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Are you using tables for layouts?**

Well, first I want to ask whether this is inside a table because you're using a table for layout.
If so, [you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).

**1. Sizing**

I would suggest that you rather set the size of the anchor than the cell (see the snippet below).

**2. Vertical Centering**

The old hack to get vertical centering was to space elements with known heights 50% from the top and then use a negative margin of half the height to correct:

```css
margin-top: -35px;
top: 50%;
```

Now there's a great feature called [`calc`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) which is even [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) and much nicer (thanks @billynoah for reminding me):

```css
top: calc(50% - 35px);
```

**3. Use the :after element**

There's also a wonderful pseudo element called [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter). You don't need to nest an img in every anchor tag; you can just do this:

```css
a:after {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b8Bn.png");
  /* You need a few more styles, see the snippet */
}
```

**Try the snippet...**

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 244px;
  height: 186px;
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Amy_Grant_on_Stage_at_the_Peppermill_Concert_Hall_in_West_Wendover,_Nevada.jpg/1024px-Amy_Grant_on_Stage_at_the_Peppermill_Concert_Hall_in_West_Wendover,_Nevada.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
a:after {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 35px);
  left: calc(50% - 35px);
  content: " ";
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b8Bn.png");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Even better:** At this point I would recommend that you consider using the `:after` trick and then using an actual `<img>` for your background:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 244px;
  height: 186px;
}
a:after {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 35px);
  left: calc(50% - 35px);
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b8Bn.png");
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Amy_Grant_on_Stage_at_the_Peppermill_Concert_Hall_in_West_Wendover,_Nevada.jpg/1024px-Amy_Grant_on_Stage_at_the_Peppermill_Concert_Hall_in_West_Wendover,_Nevada.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: This solves part of the problem, but the image is no longer centered vertically.  It is only centered horizontally.  Using the image's margin works to push it down to be centered, but then that margin value is tied to that background size.  Can this be made more generic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, if you know the size of both images then it's pretty straightforward - you just do the math. Given a consistently sized play button (70x70 here), you can use the method I've switched to (setting a negative `margin` to compensate for `top:50%`)

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block` to your `<a>` style:

```
<a href="action.htm" style="display:inline-block;height:100%;width:100%;" >
```

`<a>` tags are `display: inline` by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center;
```

That is the correct property to get the content aligned to the center.

For the image size did you confirm it is in fact as large as the td cell?

Answer (score 0):

I used the band pic as a video poster then wrapped the video element with the anchor. Use your browser <kbd>back</kbd> button or your <kbd>back key</kbd> to exit the video.

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
anachor.addEventListener('click', play, true);
var test = document.getElementById('test');

function play(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  if (test.paused) {

    test.play();
    img.style.left = "-9999px";
    a.style.style.backgroundSize = '0%';
  } else {
    test.pause();
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  background: url("https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/photo.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
video {
  top: -20px;
  position: relative;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <a href="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs2s3.mp4" target='_self'>
          <video id="test" poster="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pzdk.png" controls height="auto" width="100%">
            < source src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs2s3.mp4" />



          </video>
        </a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is your background image is curiously lacking kittens.

Also, note there is no such thing as `text-align: middle`.  You should use `text-align: center` instead.

Beyond that, you can use absolute positioning taking into account your icon size.  I like `calc` for this but there are a plethora of ways to accomplish the same thing as demonstrated in some of the other answers. I solved it like this:

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="background:url('http://zuma-design.com/shared/so/kittens.jpg') no-repeat center;background-size:100%;position:relative;width: 700px; height: 500px;">
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('meow')" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; height: 100%; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" >
    <img style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 95px); left: calc(50% - 95px);" src="http://zuma-design.com/shared/so/play.png"/>
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```